# PDF shows weird and funny characters

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-reader

I downloaded  FDF file from a website but when i opened that file it shows me some kind of weird characters.
I searched for solution on internet and discuss about it on adobe community forms. They told me this problem is because of fonts, which is not supported by PDF file or system. I already tried this file to open in google docs and other online PDF viewers. I faced this kind of problem many times in past.
Finally I am not able to solve this problem.
My system configuration is given below-
OS - windows 7
Adobe reader version - 11.0.3 (latest). Downloaded last night.
Ram - 3Gb
Processor - intel i3

My PDF Reader's font properties (Under file menu -> properties -> document properties -> font tab )
Arial -bold
ArialMT
Cambria
Devlys-010
TimesNewRomansPS-BoldMT
TimesNewRomanPSMT
Verdana 
For all fonts types = True type , actual font size = True type and encoding = Ansi

Is there any other way to open this PDF file.

Link of that PDF is given below, you can download and check that PDF file on your own system. File size is 50.5 KB.

http://www.mhsonline9.rajasthan.gov.in/Documents/Vigayapti.pdf

Please suggest solutions. Thank you.

Comment: This is not related to programming is it?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Actually it is, I need to attach this file with my website. Yes it not directly related to hardcore programming but it is necessary to me for website development. so related to programming but not directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the font Devlys-010 is used in the document but the font is not embedded. The font cannot be located on the local machine so it is substituted. The solution is to recreate the document and embed all the fonts.

PS: The question is not related to programming at all.